# Angular subscribe, how do I make a method have a subscription

Tags: angular, callback, ionic2, promise, subscribe

I'm new to Angular 2 and not sure how to do subscriptions.
I have a Member service that looks something like (simple version):

```
import { Injectable, NgZone, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { HttpProvider } from '../providers/http-provider';

@Injectable()
export class Member {

  firstName:string = "";
  surname:string = "";

  constructor(private httpProvider: HttpProvider, private network: Network, zone: NgZone) {
  }

  createMember(member){
    this.httpProvider.createMember(member).subscribe(
      result => {
        var data = JSON.parse( result['_body'] );
        this.firstName = member.FirstName;
        this.surname = member.Surname;
        return true;
      },
      err =>{
        console.error("Error : "+err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

then I have another component that uses the member service and I want to have something like:

```
this.member.createMember(member).subscribe(data)....
```

so I can check the member was created successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

Component

```
 this.membersService.createMember(member)
     .subscribe(res => {
         console.log('success', res)
        }, err => {
          console.log('error', err);
        });
```

Service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

  createMember(member) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(member);
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.post('/api/members', body, options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: I'll not bother finishing my answer, it's virtually the same - but you should mention that `createMember` won't actually send the request until something subscribes to it. (The alternative would be to use a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html))  You might also find [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) useful for typescript snippets